# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: /base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a/libmediastreamer.so" on linphone-sdk-android:5.2.70

Tags: java, android, kotlin, linphone, linphone-sdk

I am currently trying to integrate the LinPhone SDK **'org.linphone:linphone-sdk-android:5.2.70'** into my application. When I try to initiate the factory

```
    fun initCore() {
       val factory = Factory.instance()
       factory.setDebugMode(true, "Hello Linphone")
       core = factory.createCore(null, null, getApplication())
    }
```

I am getting the following error:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "__emutls_get_address" referenced by "/data/app/~~etnr80db3rwY6xyBglTUnA==/package_id-XCdnucrbTwRLEvQ0pmlAmw==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a/libmediastreamer.so"
```

Any insight on this is highly appreciated. Please let me know if further information is required for better clarification.

Comment: I am also looking for this solution. Also Bluetooth connected device is not working as output audio device.

Comment: I have found the solution. Please check the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After investigating the issue, I have found out that the problem is within the Gradle dependency configuration where the required **.so** files are not being downloaded correctly. I have followed the following steps to resolve the issue

1. First, I downloaded the latest SDK from [this](https://download.linphone.org/releases/maven_repository/org/linphone/linphone-sdk-android/) link.
2. Copied the **.aar** file to the libs directory of my project.
3. In the app-level **build.gradle** file included the .aar file:

```html
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar', '*.aar'])
    // other dependencies
}
```

Comment: This answer looks like it was generated by an AI (like ChatGPT), not by an actual human being. You should be aware that [posting AI-generated output is officially **BANNED** on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If this answer was indeed generated by an AI, then I strongly suggest you delete it before you get yourself into even bigger trouble: **WE TAKE PLAGIARISM SERIOUSLY HERE.** Please read: [Why posting GPT and ChatGPT generated answers is not currently allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy).

Comment: @tchrist, I have found the solution all by myself and AI was no help for finding the issue. Yes, I used Ai to rewrite my answer so that it was more concise and arranged. If, this is against the law then I will refactor the answer to the original state.